# Objective-C: Convert the entire double value to string without losing data

Tags: objective-c, string, nsstring, double

I have the following double value: `0.000900137869045636`
which I would like to convert to a `NSString`.

I've tried the following code, but no matter what, it rounds the value to this: `0.000900138`

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.20lf", [currentLocation coordinate].latitude];
```

What should I do to keep the double number as it is?

Thank you.

Comment: How are you inspecting the value of the resulting string?

Comment: It doesn't truncate for me, are you sure your double contains that value?

Comment: Keep in mind that running the above statement will not modify `latitude` somehow so that it later prints in wider format.  You need to use the output of the `stringWithFormat` call.

Comment: I see the values during the debug, using a breakpoint.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Create an NSNumber using

`NSNumber *myDoubleNumber = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:myDouble];`

Then call

`[myDoubleNumber stringValue];`

Comment: +1 even if I prefer *@(myDouble)* instead of *[NSNumber numberWithDouble:myDouble]*.

Comment: This relies on `NSNumber`'s internal formatting, and isn't a great way to get a precisely-defined output.

Comment: Thank you, works great. It also rounds the number a little, but only the last digit, I can live with it :)

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: use `%.18lf` - tested with 0.000900137869045633 -> 0.000900137869045639. But don't kid yourself this is precise, it works only due to rounding.

Comment: So .18lf and .20lf round the number differently ?

Comment: @thedp - First the number you have has 18 decimal places, not 20. When you format a decimal the last digit is rounded. Your decimal number does not have an exact binary equivalent, but the binary when rounded to 18 decimal digits matches, rounded to 20 it does not. Double precision floats only really have 15-17 digits of decimal precision so you are pushing the limit here, hence my comment that this is not precise - you are lucky your 18 digit number comes out the same. If you need numbers with this precision look at using NSDecimalNumber, it has up to 38 digits of precision.

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be ANY issue with your code as far as I can see: I just tried the following and

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    double foo = 0.000900137869045636;
    NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.20lf", foo]);

    return 0;
}
```

the log output is:

```
2013-05-10 14:00:18.492 Test[71101:303] 
0.00090013786904563598
```

So not sure what your issue is, but it's not in the NSString creation.